# How to import single spa app into simple html page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-spa

Created a react app and then converted it into a single spa react app using
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8oaySHuj3Y

When a hit is made to http://localhost:8080/org-app.js I get a response of the javascript files.
Also when http://single-spa-playground.org/playground/instant-test?name=@org/app&url=8080 the app loads.

However now trying to import the same app in an html page does not replaces the  tag.However, it loads the component know this because of the api calls being made and redux store being loaded.

Have not done singleSpa.registerApplication even if I do it is it necessary a root component needs to be made to register the application.

org-app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import singleSpaReact from "single-spa-react";
import Root from "./root.component";
import il8n from "./i18n";

const domElementGetter = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("example-app");
  if (!el) {
    el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "example-app";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
  return el;
};

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  il8n,
  rootComponent: Root,
  errorBoundary(err, info, props) {
    // Customize the root error boundary for your microfrontend here.
    return null;
  },
  domElementGetter,
});

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles;
```

TestPage.html Directly opened

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.5/runtime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/import-map-overrides@2.3.0/dist/import-map-overrides.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/extras/amd.js"></script>
    <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap" />
    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
          "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js",
          "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
          "rxjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/rxjs/system/es2015/rxjs.min.js",
          "rxjs/operators": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/rxjs/system/es2015/rxjs-operators.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>

    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "@example/app": "http://localhost:8080/org-app.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      System.import("@example/app");
    </script>
    <div id="example-app"></div>

   

    <h1></h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <import-map-overrides-full
      show-when-local-storage="devtools"
      dev-libs
    ></import-map-overrides-full>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to bypass single-spa entirely. The root config should be where the applications get registered which creates the association between routes and applications and dictates when they will be mounted/unmounted. Simply calling `System.import("@example/app");` is not enough because the applications do not manage their own lifecycles. Instead you could do something like this:

```js
System.import("single-spa").then(({ registerApplication, start }) => {
  registerApplication({
    name: "@example/app",
    app: () => System.import("@example/app"),
    activeWhen: ["/"],
  });
  
  start({
    urlRerouteOnly: true,
  });
});
```

I cannot see a benefit do doing it this way over what create-single-spa provides.

Lastly, it seems that you're trying to do this to control where the applications are being mounted to. There are two ways to do this with what single-spa already provides:

- Using [single-spa-layout](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/layout-definition#html-layouts) you can simply create all the intermediate DOM nodes
- Use the [`domElementGetter` option](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-react/#options) of the corresponding framework helpers to designate where the application should mount to.